# function to insert data into a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql

I'm trying to insert elements of the text field into a table when a button is clicked using function, 'Not' indicates default seat and 'yes' compliant seat. the function must also return true when all field are red else it returns false. the question is well explained in [here](https://codepen.io/Mwafrika/pen/PgYOaL?editors=1111)

```
var body = [];

function check2() {
  for (let seat = 1; seat<=36; seat++) {
     if(document.getElementById("s"+seat).value >= document.getElementById("s"+(seat+1)).value){
        document.getElementById("s"+seat).style.background="red";

        body+= document.innerHTML("<td>"+Not+"</td>");
     } else {
        document.getElementById("s"+seat).style.background="green";
        body+=document.innerHTML("<tr>" +"<td>"+Yes+"</td>");
     }   
  }
}
```

result must be inserted into a table when the condition is respected.

Comment: Skipping the fact of concatenating arrays (`body+=`), can you explain what is this `document.innerHTML("<tr>" +"<td>"+Yes+"</td>")`?

Comment: I would like just to use html into javascript file. but the question is well described in the comment to the link above. if possible you can help me to read my comment into javascript file by clicking the link  https://codepen.io/Mwafrika/pen/PgYOaL?editors=1111.

Comment: document.innerHTML("<tr>" +"<td>"+Yes+"</td>") , it is just a code to test that the seat is compliant depending on the comment in my javascript file